# Preparing project for migration from AngularJS to Angular2+ by changing controllers to components

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Hello I have a project that I inherited from others a while back. The project was originally built using AngularJS. I am currently attempting to prepare for migrating the project to Angular2. I was attempting to switch my controllers over to components. When I attempt to change

```
angular.module('main').controller...
```

to

```
angular.module('main').component...
```

it complains that the property 'component' does not exist on type 'IModule'

From my googling I suspect that it is tied to typings (the project is currently utilizing typescript) but I am having trouble figuring out how to update this. when I run npm list on the project the first few lines return

```
 @types/angular@1.7.3
+-- @types/angular-ui-bootstrap@0.13.47
| `-- @types/angular@1.7.3 deduped
+-- angular@1.7.8
+-- angular-route@1.7.8
```

further down I have

```
|   `-- typescript@1.6.2
```

obviously I did not originally set up this project so im learning how this whole set up works. Please let me know what further information is needed.

Comment: Why Angular 2 and not the latest version?

Comment: Can you click through on the IModule interface and check what version it really is? The version you list includes the component interface.

Comment: @Alexander
From everything I have read it is easiest to upgrade from js to 2 then go to the latest which is my plan

the top of the angular.d.ts file says 

// Type definitions for Angular JS 1.4+
// Project: http://angularjs.org
// Definitions by: Diego Vilar <http://github.com/diegovilar>
// Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: You need the type definitions for at least 1.5+ because in that version they added components.In my experience its better to upgrade to the latest version. When you finish the upgrade to Angular 2, you can start again upgrading to the latest version. Angular cli, Http client, rxjs, TypeScript, 3rd party dependencies,...

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Forgive my ignorance, but I don't fully understand how to update the type definitions though. According to npm I have the most recent version of @types/angular.

Comment: What version is in the package.json for the Angular types? Is there a package.lock file? What version of NPM? To me it seems that not the correct package is downloaded.

Comment: package.json says  "@types/angular": "^1.7.3", while package-lock.json says  "@types/angular": {
      "version": "1.7.3",

Comment: Strange, delete it in node_module and try reinstall? Because when you click through it goes to a 1.4 version. Where is that file located?

Comment: is the import of IModule correct?

Comment: ok I think you are on to something. When I deleted the node modules>@types>angular and did npm install and it put the type definitions for 1.7 in the node modules folder but it seems like it is pulling it from a separate subfolder which is (root directory) > FrontEnd > typings which still has the definitions for 1.4